# Magento xml action path

Tags: php, model-view-controller, magento

I have the following magento XML code:

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>myorders</name><path>chepri/myorders/customer</path><label>Standing Orders</label></action>
```

I was wondering where you would go about coding the handler for the "chepri/myorders/customer"  how does it know which page is being loaded?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [the controller dispatch](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-3-magento-controller-dispatch).